# D3 access nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some nested data in this format:

```
[{"key":"PFOA",
  "values":[
     {"sampleDate":"2016-0126T05:00:00.000Z",
      "shortName":"PFOA",
      "pfcLevel":0,
      "chemID":1},
     {"sampleDate":"2016-01-19T05:00:00.000Z",
      "shortName":"PFOA",
      "pfcLevel":0,
      "chemID":1},
     {"sampleDate":"2016-01-12T05:00:00.000Z",
      "shortName":"PFOA",
      "pfcLevel":0,
      "chemID":1}
   ],
   "visible":0}
]
```

I'm trying to use this data to add circles to a multi-line graph.  I can do this if I use the raw, non-nested data directly from the database, but that is causing other issues.  I'd rather use the same nested data for the lines and the circles if possible.  The nest function and the circle code is below:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.shortName; })
        .entries(data);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circle")
        .data(nested_data) 
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "circle");

circles.append("circle")
        .attr("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); })
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return x(d.values['sampleDate']) })
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return y(d.values['pfcLevel']) })
        .attr("r", 2);
```

I've tried different things like `d.values[sampleDate]` or `.data(nested_data.values)` but I am getting undefined errors on all of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of doing `circles.append("circle")`, try doing a second enter statement: `circles.selectAll("circle").data(...).enter().append("circle")` where `data(...)` returns the local `values` array.

Comment: That would work, but I also need access to some of the higher level elements such as d.key and d.visible.  Anyway to be able to access them all?

Comment: You can pass them through in the data function if that will suit your needs. `circles.selectAll("circle").data(function (d) {var tempArr = []; for (var x = 0; x < d.values.length; x++) tempArr.push({key: d.key, value: d.values[x], visible: d.visible}); return tempArr; });` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/armarchm/bbwgv3tr/) (I commented a couple things out since I don't have the scales).

Comment: What @JSBob is describing is called a nested selection.  Here's a [great article](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#data) on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Nested Selection](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/):

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.shortName;
  })
  .entries(data);

var groups = svg.selectAll(".circle")
  .data(nested_data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "circle");

var circles = groups.selectAll("circle") // start a nested selection
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values; // tell d3 where the children are
  })
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("stroke", function(d) {
    return color(d.shortName);
  })
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return x(d.sampleDate) // use the fields directly; no reference to "values"
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return y(d.pfcLevel)
  })
  .attr("r", 2);
```